# Array algorithm to fill an array in equal but alternate binary choices as close as possible given an already fixed configuration

Tags: algorithms, arrays

Stuck on a problem with my roommate and can't seem to find any parallels to this.

The problem is simple to understand: you have two possible binary options: T or F.

You are given an array which already has some of these options filled out e.g.

[T, X, X, F, X, T] - (Here X means unfilled)

What we want to do is to fill this array out such that the number of Ts and Fs are as equal as possible, and that they are as close to alternating as possible. The key word is approximation here, they don't have to be strictly equal or strictly alternating. Some leeway is fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does it has to be randomly filled by you?

Comment: `Any thoughts?` That's *my* line. (Yes I have - unflattering ones.)

Comment: Not sure I understand. The pre existing configuration can be considered random, but it will have at least two spaces filled. 
We can sort of consider that the rest be randomly filled as long as it adheres to making it alternate and keeping the two values even (as much as possible)

Comment: You have listed two goals you want to optimize: minimize difference in number of T's and F's, and make it as close to alternating as possible.  However, it is not possible to optimize both simultaneously; there is a tradeoff, where improving one hurts the other.  To make this a well-defined task, you must specify how you want to trade them off against each other.  In particular, please specify the exact objective function you want to minimize -- it must be one quantity, not two.

Comment: Once you define the problem completely, you can try dynamic programming, though perhaps there are faster solutions, depending on the exact problem.